# Use an R chart in a C# windows form

Tags: c#, .net, r, wpf-controls, rcharts

I have a C# code that uses some input from a windows form to do some calculation. These are mainly textbox in which the user input some data. Once a button is clicked and a calculation is done, I would like to see the results in a chart. I have seen that R has nice charts and I would need in particular a boxplot chart. Is it possible to "install" the R chart in my windows form? I am already able to generate a plot in R using C# (and RDotNet) but the chart is separated from my windows form while I would like to embed the chart in the form.